# What is the lowest Luck score where you "feel lucky?"

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Specifically referring to casinos, what is the lowest score at which you will "feel lucky?"

In my current playthrough, where my Luck is 5, I have not yet felt lucky, but have spent well over two hours at various casinos.

I'm wondering if my luck is just too low to "feel lucky."

Comment: Must destroy all typos! Must earn Strunk & White!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luck 5 is a very average Stat (Starting Stat) it is very unusual to get the "you feel lucky" message.

On my first playthrough (Luck 5), I never got that message either. Now with a starting Luck of 7 (+1 Luck-Implant), I see it very often when I play at the casinos.

So it seems that Luck 5 is Standard, you're not very lucky nor unlucky; anything above 5 will cause you to get the "feel lucky" message.